# How the .aspx page will contain the user control .ascx page?

Tags: asp.net

i have to create a “aspx” page called “ViewMessageDetail.aspx” which will contain user control “ucViewMessageDetail.ascx”. Since it will be display as lyte box popup. How can i do that??

Answer (score 1):

Try this page

http://www.asp101.com/lessons/usercontrols.asp